# Entity Framework DB select with Skip and Take fetches the entire table

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following EF code

```
Func<CxForumArticle, bool> whereClause = a => a.CreatedBy == authorId;

IEnumerable<CxForumArticle> articlesCol = ctx.Articles
              .Where(whereClause)
              .Where(a => a.PublishingStatus == EnPublishStatus.PUBLISHED)
              .OrderByDescending(a => a.ModifiedOn).Skip(offset).Take(pageSize);
```

It produces the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ArticleId] AS [ArticleId], 
    [Extent1].[Alias] AS [Alias], 
    [Extent1].[MigratedId] AS [MigratedId], 
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
    [Extent1].[Teaser] AS [Teaser], 
    [Extent1].[ClobId] AS [ClobId], 
    [Extent1].[UnifiedContentId] AS [UnifiedContentId], 
    [Extent1].[EditorComments] AS [EditorComments], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedOn] AS [CreatedOn], 
    [Extent1].[CreatedBy] AS [CreatedBy], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedOn] AS [ModifiedOn], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedBy] AS [ModifiedBy], 
    [Extent1].[PublishingStatus] AS [PublishingStatus]
    FROM [dbo].[ForumArticle] AS [Extent1]
```

As you see, there is no ordering and paging in this SQL. So EF orders and pages data in memory. 
This doesn't seem to be a good thing to do.

I read an article, claiming that I have to use expression in OrderBy clause. I did that

```
Func<CxForumArticle, bool> whereClause = a => a.CreatedBy == authorId;

Expression<Func<CxForumArticle, DateTime>> orderByFunc = a => a.ModifiedOn; 

IEnumerable<CxForumArticle> articlesCol = ctx.Articles
              .Where(whereClause)
              .Where(a => a.PublishingStatus == EnPublishStatus.PUBLISHED)
              .OrderByDescending(orderByFunc.Compile()).Skip(offset).Take(pageSize)
              ;
```

But I got the same result. Any ideas how can I force EF to sort and page the data in DB?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but you actually need to have the whereClause use an expression as well. Entity Framework only knows how to convert expressions to SQL. If you use a delegate instead of an expression, it is going to query the entire table and then then filter using LINQ to Objects.